# Smoothscroll with RecyclerView put item on bottom of list

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I want the user to be able to navigate to certain positions within a `RecyclerView`. I can determine the position of the items and when I use  `recycleView.smoothScrollToPosition()` it scrolls to the correct item.
The problem is this item is at the bottom of the screen.  How can I scroll so that the item appears at the top (it must be the first visible item).

Here is the code I use to setup the `RecyclerView`:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
recyclerView.setAdapter(actionAdapter);
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(InteractionTimelineActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerScrollListner());
```

And this is how I scroll:

```
if (recycleView != null) {               
    recycleView.smoothScrollToPosition(position + 1);
}
```

Comment: Don't use code snippets... There are just for HTML or javascript which can be run in the browser. For every programming language use normal code blocks. And it also wouldn't hurt if you would format your code properly and improve your spelling... I already fixed all that in your answer this time, but next time try to get it right yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate how many items fit on one screen and use that as offset when you scroll! You can use the methods `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` and `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` of the `LayoutManager` to calculate the offset like this:

```
int offset = getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() 
           - getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

And once you have the offset you can scroll like this:

```
recycleView.smoothScrollToPosition(Math.min(position + offset + 1, adapter.getItemCount()));
```

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. There are some extra `)` after the `getLayoutManager()` calls. And aside from that this method only works when all items in the `RecyclerView` have the same height. I also fixed a few formatting issues with your post...